# Assembly 8086 program that calculates c = ((22-7)/5)*113

Tags: assembly, x86-16

hi i really have no idea how this is working

```
data segment
 db 22
 db 7
 db 5
 db 113
data ends
code segment
 assume cs:code,ds:data
start:mov si,500H
 mov di,1500H
 mov ah,0
 mov al,22
 cbw
 sub ax,7
 mov cx,5
 idiv cx
 mov bx,113
 imul bx
 mov dl,ax
 mov [di],al
 code ends
end start
```

i really don't know what's going on in this program so any help would be appreciated

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? And is this homework?

Comment: If I were you I'd use Google to find some decent tutorial on assembly programming. There are also [developer's manuals](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253666.pdf) (e.g. from Intel) that describe each and every assembly function, which you can consult if you find something you don't understand (such as `cbw`).

Comment: `mov cs, 5` is an illegal mnemonic.  Are you trying to do `mov cx, 5`?

Comment: yeah it's mov `cx, 5`
and no it's not a homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general code not looks correct. But anyway let's review main parts:

`data segment` - declares 3 bytes of data that would be used for calc (but unfortunately doesn't used at all). `db` - is declaration of byte (compare with dw - **d** eclare **w** ord, ...)
`code segment` - declares that program code starts there

totally for perform calculation you need only following:

```
mov AX, 22; place number 22 to processor register AX
sub AX, 7; now we have subtract 7 from AX and place it back to AX
mov CX, 5; 5 is placed to CX register
xor DX, DX; per comment of @GJ
idiv cx ; divide AX / CX
mov bx,113; BX now contains 113
imul bx; at last mul result of AX on BX and place back to AX
```

Comment: well thanks man but i still have a question
can i choose any registers to do this or what?
can i for example use bx to store 22 instead of ax and then use ax to store 113??

Comment: @Max for some operation yes, you can place 22 or sub 7 from BX. But some operation (div / idiv / mul / imul ) can be performed with AX only. But you have to study these questions systematically take some book on assembly language (e.g. http://www.arl.wustl.edu/~lockwood/class/cs306/books/artofasm/toc.html)

Comment: Almost correct code... :) You must set `DX` register to 0 before `idiv` execution!

Comment: @GJ per http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/8086_instruction_set/8086_instruction_set.html#IMUL the DX will be populated for case when I use `bx` (in compare with `bl`)

Comment: @Dewfy: You divide with 16 bit CX register so the CPU calcolate: `AX = (DX:AX) / CX` therfore (in your case) you must clear `DX` register first. Check your link again!

Comment: @GJ imul responsible on multiplication, not division!

Comment: @Dewfy: I'm talking about `IDIV`, look the forth line of your sample code! Carefully read my message again!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some useful tips:

- `mov dst, src` copies the src into the dest
- `operand *dst*, src` performs the operand on the src and the dest and copies the result into the dest.  For instance, `sub ax, 7` calculates `ax - 7` and puts the result in `ax`.
- `idiv src` multiplies the src by ax, and puts the result in ax.  `imul` does the same with multiplication.

This should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
mov word[c],((22-7)/5)*113
```